# How Do I Stub webpack's require.ensure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js, sinon

I use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org)'s code splitting feature ([require.ensure](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#require-ensure-)) to reduce the initial bundle size of my [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) application by loading components that are not visible on page load from a separate bundle that is loaded asynchronously.

This works perfectly, *but* I have trouble writing a unit test for it.

My test setup is based on [Mocha](https://mochajs.org), [Chai](http://chaijs.com) and [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org).

Here is the relevant excerpt from the code I have tried so far:

```
describe('When I render the component', () => {
    let component,
        mySandbox;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mySandbox = sandbox.create();
        mySandbox.stub(require, 'ensure');
        component = mount(<PageHeader />);
    });
    describe('the rendered component', () =>
        it('contains the SideNav component', () =>
            component.find(SideNav).should.have.length(1)
        )
    );
    afterEach(() => mySandbox.restore());
});
```

When running the test, I get this error message:

> "before each" hook for "contains the SideNav component": Cannot stub non-existent own property ensure

This happens because `require.ensure` is a method that only exists in a webpack bundle, but I'm not bundling my tests with webpack, nor do I want to, because it would create more overhead and presumably longer test execution times.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to stub webpack's `require.ensure` with Sinon without running the tests through webpack?**

Comment: You are correct.Every module gets a unique `require` function.  It's pretty complicated than I thought. You can read about this more [here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/). It will be very hard to monkey patch `require.esnure`. I also suggest you to consider something like babel-plugin-rewire  which suggested by @hinok

Comment: Your issue has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070482/writing-tests-for-javascript-module-using-webpacks-require-ensure-function

Comment: The thing is, I evaluated using rewire when I started my project and found that Mockery is a far superior, so I guess I'll have to figure out how to use the rewire solution from that post with Mockery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each module has its own instance of require so the only way to mock `require.ensure` is to have some kind of abstraction around `require` to get this unique `require` from the required module in test and then add a mock of `ensure()` to that `require` instance.

You could use [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) and use getter to get `require`, like

```
const require = myComponent.__get__('require');
require.ensure = () => { /* mock here */};
```

I'm not 100% sure that it will work but definitely I would try to go in this direction. I recommend reading [this issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1064#issuecomment-270326360) on github which is related to your problem and explains a lot.